# C++ or D: idiom to decouple classes without dynamic dispatch?

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns, d, dynamic-dispatch

I am a true lover of performance, but I am aware about the importance of execute automated tests too (until better formal verification methods become mainstream).

The drawback is that when you try to design for testability you start to introduce interfaces to represent your dependencies. As you know, interfaces make your invocations dynamic dispatched over that dependency and reduce the optimization opportunities at compile-time.

```
class MyDependency
{
    void someMethod();
}

class MyUnit
{
    // Concrete type reference of MyDependency allows 
    // to bypass the dynamic dispatch
    this(MyDependency mayBeAMock)
    {
        mayBeAMock.someMethod();
    }

    unittest
    {
        // Now how can I get a mock of my dependency without to instantiate it.
        auto dep = someBlackMagic.getMock();
        auto uut = new MyUnit(dep);
    }
}
```

Does exist a better way to unit test classes without take the dynamic dispatch cost at production. If need, I would can to afford that cost for the unit testing execution but not for the production release.

Im am interested in D and C++ solutions.

Comment: You may use `template` in C++ for dependencies.

Comment: CRTP may be of interest to you?

Comment: A more concrete example of one or two such classes would help, with an explanation of where you'd need an interface to enable unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

One technique I use in D very often is to do compile-time policy replacement:

```
private struct MyUtilImpl ( HTTPClient )
{
    void foo ( )
    {
        HTTPClient.makeRequest("url");
    }
}

version (unittest)
    alias MyUtil = MyUtilImpl!FakeHTTPClient;
else
    alias MyUtil = MyUtilImpl!RealHTTPClient;
```

It is very similar to classical dependency injection in spirit but instead of mocking I/O utilities and swapping via interfaces, I do the same at compile time using template parameters.

It also has the benefit of not needing to change anything in rest of the program to start passing interface around.

Comment: I like this approach, is it scalable to large projects? what do you think?

Comment: It requires quite strict modularization / encapsulation of your project, most importantly any I/O utils must only act as consumers/producers of data and don't affect any shared program logic directly.

It also implicitly requires more procedural design with minimal exposed state across module boundaries as mocked template arguments have to be either state-less or global.

Answer (score 1):

2 ideas.
You could either make MyUnit a template and pass in a class that implements (or mocks) "someMethod"

Or, if your unit tests rebuild the class you are testing, you could define the Mock and the real version of the class in separate files and conditionally include / link to the one you want.

Of course you have to be careful not to make your tested version too different from the non-test version.